# Splitting string using delayed expansion limitation

Tags: batch-file

When I was testing a script I came across this issue when trying to extract characters from a string using batch. I have simplified it into a simple example. `t.txt` just contains the word `hello`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=0
set b=1
for /f %%a in (t.txt) do (
set x=%%a
echo !x:~!a!,!b!!
set /a x+=1
)
pause >nul
```

The problem is, the variable `x` needs to be accessed using delayed expansion, and because I am updating the values of `a` and `b` through the loop these also need to be accessed using delayed expansion.

When trying to use the variables `a` and `b` to split the string they all need delayed expansion, but the order of the `!` marks means that it is not parsed the way I intended!

CMD will expand my command as `!x:~!`, `!,!` and `!!`, instead of expanding the inner ones first. Obviously I can't use `%`'s either.

The only way I have found to get around this is to call an external function that isn't in the loop, so I can use `%`'s.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=0
set b=1
set v=
for /f %%a in (t.txt) do (
set x=%%a
call :RETURN x
set /a x+=1
)
pause >nul

:RETURN
set v=%1
echo %v:~!a!,!b!%
```

Is there any way of getting cmd to parse my command how I need it to, or this just a limitation I will have to use `call` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply transfer variables `a` and `b` to FOR variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=0
set b=1
for /f %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set "x=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("%a% %b%") do echo !x:~%%A,%%B!
  REM this line makes no sense if x=hello: set /a x+=1
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: And even this is too complex

Answer (score 3):

Mixing delayed and normal expansion will work.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=0
set b=1
for /f %%L in (t.txt) do (
  set "x=%%L"
  echo !x:~%A%,%B%!
)
```

Comment: +1: true. I thought of that, but I assumed the OP had a legitimate reason why immediate expansion could not be used. The question implies the example code was a simplification, and I assumed it just wasn't a good example.